# why DAC isn't sufficient for Android that it needs MAC(selinux)

Tags: security, selinux

I learned that each app is assigned a separate UID so that a rogue app cannot access other apps data and system sensetive data and files.

What's problem with this that they have to use MAC(selinux)

Comment: Because **D**AC is ***discretionary***, and it's up to the *discretion* of the user/uid (humans in case of Linux distros, apps in case of Android) to enforce or relax the access policy (to files, processes, sockets etc.). **M**AC is ***mandatory***, so the access policy set by administrator / program developer (in case of Linux distro) or Google / OEM / ROM developer (in case of Android) is *mandatory*. And humans/apps (or some malware code running in their name) cannot modify it to break the desired security model. Question isn't specific to Android. You'll find better answers in Linux forums